# convert List of Dicts into a 2 deep Nested Dict

Tags: python, dictionary

Ive been banging my head against a wall for some time with this now, so hoping somebody will be able to point me in the right direction

I am writing a flask app and my query returns the following list of dictionaries (via cur.fetchall) ..

```
MyQueryResult = [{'gameID': 'game_1',
  'prediction': 41,
  'bonus': 'no',
  'userName': 'Paul'},
 {'gameID': 'game_2',
  'prediction': 77,
  'bonus': 'no',
  'userName': 'Paul'},
 {'gameID': 'game_1',
  'prediction': 62,
  'bonus': 'no',
  'userName': 'Steve'},
 {'gameID': 'game_2',
  'prediction': 77,
  'bonus': 'yes',
  'userName': 'Steve'}
]
```

I need to convert this into a nested dictionary so that i can use it to build an html table with jinja2 templating ...the table will have 'gameID' as Y axis, 'userName' as X axis,  with prediction as the value in the table.. there could be any number of games or users in any particular week

Ideally, for me to iterate over it in jinja2, i need to convert the above 'flat' list of dictionaries to a nested dictionary keyed on 'userName' and then 'gameID'  ..so that it looks like this

```
MyDict = {
  'Paul': {
      'game_1': {
                'prediction': 'home_win', 'bonus': 'no'
                  },
      'game_2': {
                'prediction': 'away_win', 'bonus': 'no'
                  }},
   'Steve': {
       'game_1': {
                'prediction': 'home_win', 'bonus': 'no'
                  },
       'game_2': {
                'prediction': 'away_win', 'bonus': 'yes'
                  }
          }
   }
```

This format will enable me to iterate over on a per user /per game basis in Jinja2 and thus enable me to build a table

Does anyone have any idea on how i can perform the above conversion ...ive been trying for ages now and really struggling to figure it out :(

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you please also share what you've tried?

Comment: ah, literally hundreds of things :( ...Im just looking for a pointer

Comment: wait why does your final output have prediction as 'away_win' but the data begins with numbers?

Comment: sorry buckeye, i was just trying to make the data more readable in the final dictionary, but forgot to change the original data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One simple way to change the format of the dictionary is to iterate over it and build a new output dictionary from scratch that matches your desired format. The easiest way to iterate over a list is a [For loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop). To make it a little bit simpler, we will utilise [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from the Python collections library to create our output dictionary.

All we will now need is one loop that iterates over your result query.

```
from collections import defaultdict

output = defaultdict(dict)

for result in myQueryResult:
    # Here we are just accessing all parameters to make the rest
    # of the code less cluttered and more readable.
    userName = result['userName']
    gameID = result['gameID']
    prediction = result['prediction']
    bonus = result['bonus']

    # Prepare our dictionary for each game.
    tmp_game_dict = {'prediction': prediction, 'bonus': bonus}

    # Add it to the output array. Note as we are using a defaultdict, 
    # we are not required to check if `userName` exists yet.
    output[userName][gameID] = tmp_game_dict
```

The format you are looking for will now be stored in `output`.

Note there are a few edge cases that the piece of code above does not capture. For example, if you receive multiple results for the same `gameID`, it would currently just overwrite it. Furthermore it assumes that `userName`, `gameID`, `prediction` and `bonus` are always part of the result array - depending on your use case you may want to add some appropriate error handling.

Comment: thanks m__z ...importing defaultdict was very helpful ..ive been trying to do it by just using standard for loops and its been causing me all sorts of issues ..this method works great, thanks

Comment: Fantastic. Please don't forget to accept my answer as a solution if it made it work :)